# Difficulty deploying Django app on Android and iPhone.. planning on switching to PHP instead of Django

Tags: php, django, web-applications, mobile-application, web-application-design

Okay so I am 1/4th finished creating a django application (where users must register an account, log in and can interact with other users of the application, basically a social network. And the application has a PostgreSQL database). I decided to do research and figure out ways to actually host this django powered social network site on the internet and make it a mobile app which can be downloaded from the android and iphone appstore. I want to first host the site, so I looked for places to host it. I found webfaction.com and this links in particular

http://docs.webfaction.com/software/django/getting-started.html

which explains how to host the djnago application. Now, I did not read over it completely but I trust that I can host my social network django application using webfaction without going through a whole bunch of trouble. (please correct me if there is someone here who did try hosting a django application and had great difficulty).

After hosting it as a site, I also want it to be a mobile application which can be used on iPhones and Androids. Now, all I want to know is, what is the least complicated way of doing this properly? (because I'm guessing all ways will be pretty complicated.. I don't want a step by step tutorial on how to do it, a simple url to a documentation on how to do it is good enough). Will I need to learn PHP, C, Java or anything else or will I be able to do this with just knowing django and python? Note that this isn't just an application where users visit and read information, it's a social network.

I just need someone to confirm to me that deploying a social network created using django and hosting it on a site is possible and then taking that app and making it an Android and iOS app without have to completely recreate it with a different language is possible. If you can provide me a link to get me started on how to take am existing django app and make it an Android app without having to completely retype the app with a different language, that would be great.

Comment: Not really sure what your asking. I have used webfaction. It is very easy to host a django site. As far as creating a mobile app, will it be a native app? You definitely cannot use django for that. You will need to learn objective c for an iOS app and java for the android.

Comment: For developing native app learn android,java, objective c.
Php Socket is just awful when it compares to python.
Just stick with it.

Comment: Okay thanks, so after I have finished creating my django app, in order to deploy the django app written in python with a postgreSQL database, how would I use Java to make it an android app and C to make it an iOS app? Any quick link to get me started will do, but how exactly do I take a django app which already has an existing UI and the HTMLand css all done and use Java to make it an Android app? Againm a link to a documentation which will get me started will suffice.

Comment: @jproffitt, I just need someone to confirm to me that deploying a social network created using django and hosting it on a site is possible and then taking that app and making it an Android and iOS app without have to completely recreate it with a different language is possible.

Comment: You cannot simply make a django app with HTML etc into an iOS or android app. Those are totally different platforms, and don't even use HTML. It just isn't possible. You could make a mobile web app, or use phonegap, but the experience isn't nearly as good in my opinion. Either way it is not going to be a simple transfer in any way.

Comment: Right, okay so the django app which I created has its views, models and forms written in python, and the templates which are created using HTML, everything else is python code. So now I want to make this django app a phone app for Android, where would I start? I would I start making it a phone app using Java? And yes I do not want to use phone gap, I want to actually know how it is done.. Is there any documentation you would recommend to just get me started on making my django app a mobile app for Android or iOS?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply put: you would create your web app (website) using Python+Django (for the back end) and HTML, JavaScript & CSS (for the front end). Once you've done this, you can make a very basic app for iOS and Android which is really just a browser window pointed to your website.

Google 'android webview' for some examples of embedding your site into an android app with Java (note this is a very basic way of doing it).

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you're understanding the fundamentals here...

A *NATIVE* app for iOS ***must*** be written in Objective C or Swift.

A *NATIVE* app for Android ***must*** be written in Java.

You simply cannot compile and deploy a web application written in Django to Objective C or Java (to the best of my knowledge).

However, it's possible to write an HTML5/JavaScript web application that can be compiled to one of the respective native platforms, using [Appcellerator](http://appcelerator.com) or [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/). The backend data provider for such an app could certainly be a REST API powered by Django.

I don't know Objective C or Java, so I stick with the tool set I know - Django, Python, HTML5, Twitter Bootstrap and JavaScript to create *mobile friendly* web apps. These are web sites using responsive CSS to format the content best for mobile and tablet viewports, but they are NOT *native* iOS or Android applications.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can have a python app compile to native C on both iOS and Android and get them accepted into the relevant app stores. Check http://kivy.org and http://Cython.org

Comment: How exactly does Kivy help with this goal?